# vb.net vbcrlf, environment.newline & vbcr is not working

Tags: vb.net

VB.Net Code

```
Dim sTest As String = "QueryLine1" & vbCrLf & "QueryLine2"
```

Current Output

> "QueryLine1" & vbCrLf & "QueryLine2"

I want to see

> QueryLine1
>
> QueryLine2

SQL Query

```
declare @now date,@dob date, @now_i int,@dob_i int, @days_in_birth_month int
declare @years int, @months int, @days int
set @now = '2013-02-28' 
set @dob = '2012-02-29' -- Date of Birth

set @now_i = convert(varchar(8),@now,112) -- iso formatted: 20130228
set @dob_i = convert(varchar(8),@dob,112) -- iso formatted: 20120229
set @years = ( @now_i - @dob_i)/10000
-- (20130228 - 20120229)/10000 = 0 years

set @months =(1200 + (month(@now)- month(@dob))*100 + day(@now) - day(@dob))/100 %12
-- (1200 + 0228 - 0229)/100 % 12 = 11 months

set @days_in_birth_month = day(dateadd(d,-1,left(convert(varchar(8),dateadd(m,1,@dob),112),6)+'01'))
set @days = (sign(day(@now) - day(@dob))+1)/2 * (day(@now) - day(@dob))
          + (sign(day(@dob) - day(@now))+1)/2 * (@days_in_birth_month - day(@dob) + day(@now))
-- ( (-1+1)/2*(28 - 29) + (1+1)/2*(29 - 29 + 28))
-- Explain: if the days of now is bigger than the days of birth, then diff the two days
--          else add the days of now and the distance from the date of birth to the end of the birth month 
select @years,@months,@days -- 0, 11, 28
```

when storing it in variable and executing the stored sql query results blank.  Because enter marks are note stored in variable.

If you copy paste the above sql query in sql query window then you will get result.  But when storing the query in vb.net variable and executing the query results nothing.

I tried to highlight this issue with a small example and that's why started with a small piece of code.

Comment: That is not the current output. That might be something that you see in the debugger but that would be because the debugger cannot display multiline text in location in which you are looking. If you call `Console.WriteLine` or `MessageBox.Show` to actually display the value of `sTest` then you will see exactly what you say you want to see. In short, the code is working but you're just not testing it correctly. That warrants a down-vote in my book, although I'm not the one who gave it.

Comment: I taken the output from Immediate window

Comment: @Sixthsense And how did it get there? Please edit your question and add a complete example since creating the variable until displaying it.

Comment: So you are indeed viewing it exactly as I said and not as I said you should. Maybe now you should view it as I said you should.

Comment: Down-votes aren't supposed to solve people's problems. They are supposed to indicate that the person didn't do enough to solve their own problem.

Comment: I think you guys are wasting the time instead of giving right solution to the person who is in need of help.

Comment: Yes, I advise @jmcilhinney to stop wasting your precious time and give you something to try. Wait, he already did that, TWICE! Never mind.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed,  I added my actual problem in the post.

Comment: If people don't understand the question, it's usually means the question isn't written in a way that people can understand it, hence the downvotes. So it mean's you should rethink your question.

Comment: I accept it.  If you ask me questions then I am ready to explain it.  But simply clicking the down button is spoiling the actual motto.

Comment: I think that this is probably a provider issue and nothing to do with line breaks at all. Whenever I've written multiple statements in the one command, I've always had a semicolon after each statement. Maybe not including those is your issue. If you do the research that you should have done in the first place and started with simple `SELECT` statement broken over multiple lines, does that produce the expected output?

Comment: It's not up to you whether people down-vote. Get over it. If people don't understand the question, it's probably your fault. In this case, it appears that you asked complete the wrong question and implied that something was happening when it wasn't. That's worth a down-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is still no way that what you said was happening was actually happening but, regardless, it doesn't even matter. If what you want is to write a multiline SQL query then you don't need to use string concatenation at all.  If you're using VB 2015 (or later) then you can actually write a multiline `String` literal, e.g.

```
        Dim query = "SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 1"
```

You can format that to make the text line up if you like because SQL doesn't care about whitespace:

```
Dim query = "SELECT *
             FROM MyTable
             WHERE ID = 1"
```

If you're using an older version of VB then you can use an XML literal:

```
        Dim sql = <sql>
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 1
                  </sql>
        Dim query = sql.Value
```

Again, you can format with whitespace if desired:

```
Dim sql = <sql>
            SELECT *
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE ID = 1
          </sql>
Dim query = sql.Value
```

If you view the value of `query` using the debugger then you should still see the same sort of thing you are now if it's somewhere that cannot display multiline `Strings` but the actual value will be exactly as it should.

Comment: Have you tried to store the given sql query in a variable and called that variable in your query output?  If you do that, then you will come to know about my problem.  Because the query result will be blank

Comment: But if you copy paste the above sql query in sql query window then it shows the results.  Because storing the above query in variable removes the enter marks and replaces it with blank or spaces I believe.

Comment: Yes, I have done this many times and it worked every time. If it's not working for you then there's something else at issue.